# Using IAM role permissions to prevent user from launching EC2 instance in CLI without a key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, key-pair

I am creating a policy for an IAM role in Terraform and that role needs to be able to launch EC2 instances from a launch template, but with some flexibility and some restrictions. One of these restrictions is that **any instance launched in the console or AWS CLI should have a key pair associated with it**, however it does not have to be a specific key pair.

I have tried using several variations on the condition in the code below (e.g. explicitly specifying a name, changing the test conditions etc)  and also tried a `Null` test with value `false`, to try to specify that the `ec2:KeyPairName` just needs to exist. None of these conditions are allowing me to launch an instance.

```
 {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2Launch",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::xxx:instance-profile/xxx",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx::image/xxx",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:volume/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:subnet/subnet-xxx",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:security-group/sg-xxx",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:launch-template/lt-xxx",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:key-pair/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:xxx:xxx:elastic-gpu/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "ec2:KeyPairName": [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

(I am defining this in Terraform, but as the question is about how to write the policy, not the TF, I've posted the policy.)

To confirm, without the condition I can launch an instance with and without a specified key. With any of the conditions I have tried, I cannot launch an instance with or without a specified key. This is all through AWS CLI.

I have also considered that `key_name` can be specified in the Terraform launch template definition, however I want the condition to be *not null* rather than restricted to one specific key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its **not possible**. `ec2:KeyPairName` condition is only valid for `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*` resources. If you launch an instance without a key, the resources `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*` are simply not used, so `ec2:KeyPairName` is never evaluated.

The workaround would be to setup AWS Config rule to check for new instances if they have the key or not, or simply setup a lambda function that is triggered whenever an instance is launched which will check for the key as well.

Comment: Ah, ok, this makes sense. Also, I see now that in my above policy it doesn't work at all because the condition is being applied to all resources in this statement, when it should only be applied to key pairs. However when I take the key pair resource out into a separate statement, with its condition, it just isn't evaluated if a key pair isn't specified, as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with just `StringLike` as your condition?

You are using the [`ForAnyValue:StringLike` set operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_String), which means you're expecting there to be multiple values for the `ec2:KeyPairName`, which I don't think is possible for EC2 instances?